# Attribute parameter types as another attribute

Tags: c#, attributes

In Java it is possible to compose annotations by declaring annotation parameters that have as type another annotation. So for example I can write this composition:

```
@interface Copyright { 
    String value();
}
@interface Trademark { 
    String value();
}
@interface IP {
    Copyright copyright();
    Trademark trademark();
}
@IP(copyright = @Copyright("2013"), trademark = @Trademark("x is a trademark of x inc"))
class MyClass{}
```

The C# language specification would seem to suggest that it is not possible to do something similar, since it states valid attribute parameter types are:

- One of the following types: bool, byte, char, double, float, int, long, sbyte, short, string, uint, ulong, ushort.
- The type object.
- The type System.Type.
- An enum type, provided it has public accessibility and the types in which it is nested (if any) also have public accessibility.
- Single-dimensional arrays of the above types.

Visual Studio flashes all kinds of red at me when I try to write:

```
[IP (copyright=[Copyright("2008")],trademark=[Trademark("x is a trademark of x, inc")]]
```

But what about this "type object" that the language specification is talking about? My attribute "is a" object by virtue of polymorphism, so is it at all possible to achieve in C# what Java allows? If not then how does "type object" work?

Comment: No, you can't do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marc Gravell says "No, you can't do that"